# Injected IPrincipal is anonymous but Web API Controller User object is authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I'm writing a Web API 2/MVC5 project and I wanted to unit test some code that had to work with an IPrincipal using ASP.Net Identity. Instead of relying on IPrincipal I wanted to abstract that behind my own IUserService. When I look at my injected `IUserService` the `UserId` and `UserName` are null.

```
public interface IUserService
{
    string UserId { get;  }
    string UserName { get;  }
}
```

The concrete implementation being used is:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IPrincipal _principal;

    public UserService(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        _principal = principal;
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _principal.Identity.GetUserName(); }

    }

    public string UserId
    {
        get { return _principal.Identity.GetUserId(); }

    }
}
```

This is using Ninject for dependency injection. Inside NinjectWebCommon.cs I have:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
   kernel.Bind<IBooksService>().To<BooksService>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<IBookRepository>().To<BookRepository>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>().InRequestScope();
   kernel.Bind<IPrincipal>().ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.User);
}
```

If I create a `Func<IPrincipal>` and pass `()=>HttpContext.Current.User` everything works fine. However, I don't see anyone needing to do this and all of the examples suggest this implementation.

Comment: Can you show us the unit test code, and identify what you are trying to test? [Moved to comment] (Thanks Paresh)

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever authenticate the user? Once the user is authenticated, you need to take care of creating an `IIdentity` and an `IPrincipal`. Then, you need to set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with the `IPrincipal`, and you also need to put the `IPrincipal` in the current `HttpContext`.

In order for a `GenericIdentity` to not be considered anonymous, the `Name` property must be a non-empty string. In order for a `ClaimsIdentity` to not be considered anonymous, the `AuthenticationType` property must be a non-null, non-empty string.

So, generally, you'll do the following:

```
// Perform authentication, usually using some kind of AuthenticationFilter or
// AuthorizationFilter.
// After authenticating, and still within the Auth*Filter,

// I'm going to use a GenericIdentity, but this can be converted to a 
// ClaimsIdentity if you're using the default Name claim.
IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity("myUserName", "myAuthenticationType");

// Again, you could use a ClaimsPrincipal, the concept, however, is the same.
IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null /* no roles */);
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

I did see that you mentioned the new ASP.Net Identity model is being used. So you'd definitely use `ClaimsIdentity` and `ClaimsPrincipal` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my guess, but this may be faulty:

```
kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>().InRequestScope();
```

First use of IUserService can occur before `HttpContext.Current.User` is set, so instead of current user, you get `null`, because at the moment `UserService` was created, `HttpContext.Current.User` was `null`. Since you have `InRequestScope()` defined, first created object of `UserService` is provided in subsequent uses, so principal is null all the time.

What I would probably do is just use `HttpContext` directly:

```
public class HttpContextBasedUserService : IUserService
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName(); }

    }

    public string UserId
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); }

    }
}
```

If you want to use `IUserService` in desktop application, create implementation dedicated for desktop use.